# vbScript read file from an specific line

Tags: vbscript, readfile, hp-uft

Hello everyone I got a doubt, about how to read a ***.txt*** file starting in specific line, I got the line number from I want to start to read, and I'm trying to read it, but always start from the first line

And it takes a several minutes to reach my needed line

Here's my code

```
'Call F_CMN_GRL_FindObjects(17,15)

strProperty = F_CMN_GRL_GlobalMain(6,17,15,0,"all items" )

strLine = split(strProperty,",")
    Print strLine(0)
strValor = split(strLine(0)," ") 
    Print strValue(1)

numberLine = strValue(1)
Call readFromLine(numberLine)
Function readFromLine(numberLine)

    numberLineEnd =numberLine + 7
    print numberLine
    print numberLineEnd
'   Option Explicit

    Dim oFso : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFile : Set oFile = oFso.OpenTextFile("C:\myFile.txt", 1)
'   Dim myArray()
'   ReDim myArray(0)

    'numberLine it's the number line from I want to start to read and I want to read until numberLineEnd            
    For i = numberLine to numberLineEnd step 1
        strLine = oFile.ReadLine

        print strLine
    Next
        'i = i + 1
        'numberLine = numberLine + 1
End Function
```

Comment: Pay your attention to the `SkipLine` method; apply it `For i = 1 to numberLine - 1`

Comment: How big is your file? If its relatively smallish, then you can store the file in an array by splitting it at linebreaks and then use arrayindex to read desired line(s)

Comment: @JosefZ You're right
If I don't make a -, it skips to next line where I want to start

Comment: @PankajJaju I tried this option, but when my file has 2500 lines or more, it is not the most convincing way.

Comment: @Lou: do not put answers into questions, not even with suggested edits. That's what answer posts are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by doing it like this:

```
Dim i 
    Do While (i <= numeroLineaFin)
        If (i => numeroLinea) and (i<=numeroLineaFin) Then
'           If i <= numeroLineaFin Then
'               tmpstr = tmpstr & oFile.readline & VbCrLf
                tmpstr = oFile.readline
                print tmpstr
'           else
'            oFile.SkipLine
'           End If
        else
            oFile.SkipLine
        end if
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```